# Running RobotFramework Selenium tests with Xvfb

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, xvfb

Following the usage as specified for [XvfbRobot](https://github.com/drobota/robotframework-xvfb), I'm running into some issues. I'm trying to run robot tests through flask, which seems to be working, but I'm getting stuck with, "No browser is open," though the virtual display seems to start fine.

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.4

# Update source repositories
RUN echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories

ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code

# Install geckodriver:
RUN export BASE_URL=https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download
RUN export VERSION=$(curl -sL https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest | grep tag_name | cut -d '"' -f 4)
RUN curl -sL $BASE_URL/$VERSION/geckodriver-$VERSION-linux64.tar.gz | tar -xz
RUN mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/geckodriver

# run Xvfb in the background with a display number
RUN Xvfb :10 -ac &
ENV DISPLAY=:10

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

requirements.txt

```
flask
robotframework
robotframework-selenium2library
robotframework-xvfb
selenium
```

Here's a link to the [app repo](https://github.com/ogryzek/rvfb_robot_flask/)

Versions:

- selenium 3.4.3
- geckodriver 16.1/18.0
- Robot Framework 3.0.2 (Python 2.7.12 on linux2)
- pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Any help/pointers in the right direction for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried playing around with different versions of robotframework-selenium2library, and selenium, but am still having the same issue.

Comment: OK wow, so I've found that using the following works:
  - Updated to alpine 3.6 (this installs firefox 52.2.0)
  - Downgraded geckodriver to 15.0
  - Downgraded Selenium to 3.3.1

Comment: According to the [Gecko Driver support page](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver#supported-firefoxen)."Support is best in Firefox 53 and greater, although generally the more recent the Firefox version, the better the experience as they have more bug fixes and features."